# scope variable is null in angular directive link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm begginer in angularjs. I have an angular directive and using it ASP.NET MVC project:

```
'use strict';
app.directive('province', function (Province, $rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<select data-ng-model="province" data-ng-options="province.provinceId as province.provinceName for province in provinces" ' +
        'data-ng-change="provinceChanged()"></select>',        
    link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {            
        Province.get().then(function (provinces) {                
            scope.provinces = provinces;
        });
        console.log(scope.provinces);
        scope.province = false;            
        scope.provinceChanged = function () {
            if (!scope.province) {
                 return;
            }
            $rootScope.$broadcast("provinceChanged", { province: scope.province });
        };
    }        
};
})
```

This is the way I use it:

```
<province id="province" class="form-control" data-selected-province="@Model.Province"/>
```

The select element shows provinces corrctly. Now I want to set a default value for select element. So I use attribute `data-selected-province` and set it to the value that I get from server(`@Model.Province`). I think I should loop through `scope.provinces` and find the index of the province whose `provinceId` is equal to `data-selected-province` attribute and set `scope.province` which is `ng-model` to that index. But `scope.provinces` is `undefined` when I print it to the console using `console.log`. I have two questions:

1. why `scope.provinces` is null?
2. Is this the correct way of setting
   default value?

**UPDATE**

I was a bit confused. The only thing I need to do is set `scope.province` to `attr.selectedProvince`. But I still have a problem. When I set `scope.province` to a constant number like `scope.province = 8` it works fine but when I set `data-selected-province = 8` it does not work. I can see in firebug that this attribute is equal to 8 when rendering the directive.

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: You are will always get undefined because .then is aynsc operation which will take some to complete so before completion of then you are printing scope.provinces which will ultimately give u undefined value

Answer (score 1):

As Ajay Beniwal pointed out in his comments, `Provience.get()` is an asynchronous operation, so you need to move the `console.log` into the callback function to make it work:

```
Province.get().then(function (provinces) {                
    scope.provinces = provinces;
    console.log(scope.provinces);
});
```

For your second question, I suggest you make a `data-selected-province-id` attribute instead of `data-selected-province`, because attributes are always strings, a simple id value is easier to deal with. Once you have that, you can then try the following in link function:

```
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    ...

    scope.provience = attr.selectedProvienceId;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually it should be `scope.province = attr.selectedProvinceid`. It does not work again. But when I set a constant number like `scope.province = 8` it works.

Comment: @Beginner I updated my answer, the attribute should be named as `data-selected-province-id`, then you can use `attr.selectedProvienceId`. Are you sure the value of your `attr.selectedProvinceid` is actually an id?

Comment: Yes. When I set a constant number it works. I even passed a constant number in the element. `data-selected-province-id = "8"`. I can see in the fire bug that this attribute is 8.

Comment: **SOLVED** As @Ye Liu mention the value should be an integer because `provinceId` that is used in `ng-option` to generate the options is integer. So `scope.province = parseInt(arrt.selectedProvince)` solved the problem. Changing `attr-selected-province` to `attr-selected-province-id` did not change the type of attribute to int.

Comment: @Beginner That's great! My suggestion is not to use an *object* in the attribute because it's not clear it's an id or an object in `data-selected-province="@Model.Province"`, it doesn't matter how the attribute is named ;)